# Dividing each element in a container between a given number C++

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I was multiplying each container against another number so I did the following:

```
local_it begin = magnitudesBegin;
std::advance(begin , 2);
local_it end  = magnitudesBegin;
std::advance(end, 14);
std::transform(begin, end, firstHalf.begin(),
  std::bind1st(std::multiplies<double>(),100));
```

It worked wonders, problem is when doing the same to divide between another container. Here is a working example of my problem:

```
const std::size_t stabilitySize = 13;
boost::array<double,stabilitySize> secondHalf;
double fundamental = 707;
boost::array<double, stabilitySize> indexes = {{3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15}};
std::transform(indexes.begin(), indexes.end(), secondHalf.begin(),
  std::bind1st(std::divides<double>(),fundamental));
```

### **It does divide the container. But instead of dividing each element in the array against 707 it divides 707 between each element in the array.**

Comment: Why not writing a lambda for this? No C++11?

Comment: How about `bind2nd` :) ?

Comment: Sorry I don't have C++11 :(

Comment: Thought that (since you're also using `boost::array`). In this case, `bind2nd` should be the perfect solution.

Comment: That is not a working example.

Comment: Sorry it is not a working example, but thanks to everyone I could keep using the std and now I have an impl that is easy to migrate to C++11 for the day we upgrade. Besides knowing that divides works differently than multiplies when using bind is not easy to infer from the bind or divides documentation. I lacked experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::bind1st(std::divides<double>(),fundamental)
```

The code above takes a functor `std::divides<double>` that takes two arguments and fixes the value of the first argument to be `fundamental`. That is it fixes the *numerator* of the operation and you get the expected result. If you want to bind `fundamental` to be the denominator, use `std::bind2nd`.

Answer (score 2):

you can try the following , divide has a completely different operation than multiply, it just divides a constant number by all your elements

```
 std::bind1st(std::multiplies<double>(),1.0/707.0));
```

Comment: Seems like the fastest and easiest solution. I thought of it but really wanted to make divides work. Thanks a lot for reming me of KISS

Comment: It might even be faster, since floating point multiplication is faster than division and `1.0/707.0` is optimized to one number by the compiler, but I don't think that a similar optimization will take place inside a bound functor like the division with `bind2nd` (so it will result in division in your assembly code). At least, this is what my instinct tolds me. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If the number `707.0` is something like a fundamental constant, and a division can be seen as a "conversion", let's call it "x to y" (I don't know what your numbers are representing, so replace this by meaningful words). It would be nice to wrap this "x to y" conversion in a free-standing function for re-usability. Then, use this function on `std::transform`.

```
double x_to_y(double x) {
    return x / 707.0;
}
...
std::transform(..., x_to_y);
```

If you had C++11 available, or want to use another lambda-library, another option is to write this in-line where being used. You might find this syntax more readable like parameter binding using `bind2nd`:

```
std::transform(..., _1 / 707.0);  // when using boost::lambda
```